# Flask Twitter OAuth fails with message - AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'oauth_token'

Tags: oauth, flask, twitter-oauth

I haven't been able to get Flask-Social to work, so am trying to provide the ability for users to log into my Flask app by following the twitter example Flask-OAuth project here:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth/blob/master/example/tweet.py

here's the code I've written (the login/register via form works fine btw):

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, g
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import app, db
from forms import RegisterForm, UniqueUser
from models import User, Connection, Role, Item, MessagesSent,Alerts
from datetime import datetime
from emails import form_notification
from .tools import requires_auth
from flask.ext.security import LoginForm, current_user, login_required, \
    login_user
from flask.ext.social.utils import get_provider_or_404
from flask.ext.social.views import connect_handler
from flask_oauth import OAuth

oauth = OAuth()

# Use Twitter as example remote application
twitter = oauth.remote_app('twitter',
    # unless absolute urls are used to make requests, this will be added
    # before all URLs.  This is also true for request_token_url and others.
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/',
    # where flask should look for new request tokens
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    # where flask should exchange the token with the remote application
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    # twitter knows two authorizatiom URLs.  /authorize and /authenticate.
    # they mostly work the same, but for sign on /authenticate is
    # expected because this will give the user a slightly different
    # user interface on the twitter side.
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate',
    # the consumer keys from the twitter application registry.
    consumer_key='xXXXXX',
    consumer_secret='XXXX'
)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

# Views
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
#@login_required
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/landing')

    return render_template('index.html')

@twitter.tokengetter
def get_twitter_token():
    """This is used by the API to look for the auth token and secret
    it should use for API calls.  During the authorization handshake
    a temporary set of token and secret is used, but afterwards this
    function has to return the token and secret.  If you don't want
    to store this in the database, consider putting it into the
    session instead.
    """
    print("in get_twitter_token")
    user = g.user
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        return user.oauth_token, user.oauth_secret

@app.route('/oauth-authorized')
@twitter.authorized_handler
def oauth_authorized(resp):
    """Called after authorization.  After this function finished handling,
    the OAuth information is removed from the session again.  When this
    happened, the tokengetter from above is used to retrieve the oauth
    token and secret.

    Because the remote application could have re-authorized the application
    it is necessary to update the values in the database.

    If the application redirected back after denying, the response passed
    to the function will be `None`.  Otherwise a dictionary with the values
    the application submitted.  Note that Twitter itself does not really
    redirect back unless the user clicks on the application name.
    """
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('index')
    if resp is None:
        flash(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
        return redirect(next_url)

    user = User.query.filter_by(name=resp['screen_name']).first()
    print(user)
    # user never signed on
    if user is None:
        user = User(resp['screen_name'])
        db_session.add(user)

    # in any case we update the authenciation token in the db
    # In case the user temporarily revoked access we will have
    # new tokens here.
    user.oauth_token = resp['oauth_token']
    user.oauth_secret = resp['oauth_token_secret']
    db_session.commit()

    session['user_id'] = user.id
    flash('You were signed in')
    return redirect(next_url)



@app.route('/login')
@app.route('/login/<provider_id>')
def login(provider_id=None):
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/landing')


    if provider_id:
        print("in provider_id")
        return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('oauth_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))

    else:
        return render_template('login.html', form=LoginForm())


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/register/<provider_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register(provider_id=None):
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/landing')

    form = RegisterForm()

    if provider_id:
        provider = get_provider_or_404(provider_id)
        connection_values = session.get('failed_login_connection', None)
    else:
        provider = None
        connection_values = None

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ds = app.security.datastore
        user = ds.create_user(email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data)
        ds.commit()

        # See if there was an attempted social login prior to registering
        # and if so use the provider connect_handler to save a connection
        connection_values = session.pop('failed_login_connection', None)

        if connection_values:
            connection_values['user_id'] = user.id
            connect_handler(connection_values, provider)

        if login_user(user):
            ds.commit()
            flash('Account created successfully', 'info')
            return redirect(url_for('rightform'))

        return render_template('thanks.html', user=user)

    login_failed = int(request.args.get('login_failed', 0))

    return render_template('register.html',
                           form=form,
                           provider=provider,
                           login_failed=login_failed,
                           connection_values=connection_values)
```

Here's the error message that I get --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_oauth.py", line 427, in decorated
  data = self.handle_oauth1_response()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_oauth.py", line 371, in handle_oauth1_response
  client = self.make_client()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_oauth.py", line 239, in make_client
  return oauth2.Client(self._consumer, self.get_request_token(token))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_oauth.py", line 312, in get_request_token
  rv = self.tokengetter_func(*(token and (token,) or ()))
File "XXXXXapp/views.py", line 63, in get_twitter_token
  return user.oauth_token, user.oauth_secret
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
  return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
```

AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'oauth_token'

I see a flash of the Twitter confirmation page before the error shows up, and I can see with logging the following:

```
in provider_id
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2014 19:49:15] "GET /login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
in get_twitter_token
<flask_security.core.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f6f504a2cd0>
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2014 19:49:16] "GET /oauth-authorized?next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fregister&oauth_token=ikXXXXXXXXGeSRZWFo6zt5bant2YU&oauth_verifier=GhvpXXXXXXsqzaqtssyymI
```